# Why am I unable to get the name of the current running script when packaged as an EXE?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Typically in my scripts, I use the following to get the name of the current script (without the extension):

```
$baseName = (Get-Item $PSCommandPath).BaseName
```

For some reason, this (and every other way I can think of to get the name of the running script) is not working when the script is packaged as an executable. I am using Powershell Pro Tools with VS Code to package the script. While I could just hard code the base code, I would prefer not to. Is there anything I can do to get around this? Any way to get the name of the executable, even though it is in reality a script?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting... I wonder if you'd have to to read it as a subexpression, or it's just not taking the variable period.

Comment: Using PSPTools, or PS2EXE, is the same result. Take a step back for a moment and think about your use case. You are checking for a script path, but running an executable, which is a process, not a script. So, getting the command path of your executable means looking at your executable process specific. What are you doing with that name, thus the need to capture it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to properly access the isnetworkdeployed property from a complied EXE (using Quest PowerGUI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65040018/is-there-a-way-to-properly-access-the-isnetworkdeployed-property-from-a-complied)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using `$baseName = [System.Diagnotics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess.Name`. That seemed to do the trick.